# Formula changes when adding new rows. How to stop this happening?

Tags: function, excel-2003, worksheet-function

I have the following formula

```
=COUNTIF('New Workplan'!$J$3:J133,"My Value")
```

The problem is that when new rows are added to the worksheet 'New Workplan' between the row 3 to 133, then the formula changes.

For example if 10 rows are added excel changes the formula to

```
=COUNTIF('New Workplan'!$J$13:J133,"My Value")
```

When this happen, then the first 10 rows (from 3 to 13) are not counted any more.

What I need is the formula to stay =COUNTIF('New Workplan'!$J$3:J133,"My Value") at all the times.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: This workbook is used by several people, and I dont know what they do to get it modified.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDIRECT to remove the formula range update, ie

=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'New Workplan'!$J$3:J133"),"My Value")

Pearson has a useful reference for INDIRECT here, http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm